# Subplot problem: how to plot for each plot a histogram by categorical values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a DataFrame with three numerical variables Porosity, Perm and AI. I would like to make a subplot and in each plot, I would like the histogram of the three variables, by a categorical variable 'Facies'. Facies can take only two values: Sand and Shale.

In summary, each subplot needs a histogram and each histogram must be drawn based in the categorical variable Facies, to make a comparison between facies.

So far, I can make it work, but I cannot add the axis title to each subplot.

```
plt.subplot(311)
plt.hist(df_sd['Porosity'].values, label='Sand', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
plt.hist(df_sh['Porosity'].values, label='Shale', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
ax.set(xlabel='Porosity (fraction)', ylabel='Density', title='Porosity              
      Histogram')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(312)
plt.hist(df_sd['log10Perm'].values, label='Sand', bins=30, alpha=0.6,)
plt.hist(df_sh['log10Perm'].values, label='Shale', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
ax.set(xlabel='Permeability (mD)', ylabel='Density', title='Permeability 
Histogram')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(313)
plt.hist(df_sd['AI'].values, label='Sand', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
plt.hist(df_sh['AI'].values, label='Shale', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
ax.set(xlabel='AI (units)', ylabel='Density', title='Acoustic Impedance 
Histogram')

plt.legend()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.5, top=3.5, wspace=0.1, 
hspace=0.2);


#I have tried with:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
but when I code
axs[0].hist(df_sd['Porosity'].values, label='Sand', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
axs[0].hist(df_sd['Porosity'].values, label='Shale', bins=30, alpha=0.6)

#But the histogram for shale overrides the histogram for Sand.
```

[I would like to have this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfyyd.png) but with both x and y axis with label names. Furthermore, it would be helpful to have a title for each subplot.

Comment: The title can be set by using `ax[0].set_title('Title here)`, `ax[1].set_title('Title here)` , `ax[2].set_title('Title here)`  and so on

Answer (score 0):

I just did a subplot with contours, but I think the framework will be very similar:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True)
for ax, extend in zip(axs.ravel(), extends):
    cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels, cmap=cmap, extend=extend, origin=origin)
    fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax, shrink=0.9)
    ax.set_title("extend = %s" % extend)
    ax.locator_params(nbins=4)
plt.show()
```

I think the main point to note (and this I learned from the link below) is their use of `zip(axs.ravel())` in the for loop to establish each `ax` and then plot what you wish on that `ax`. I'm fairly certain you can adapt this for your uses.

The full example is available at: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-demo-py

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(313)


plt.subplot(311)
ax1.hist(df_sd['Porosity'].values, label='Sand', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
ax1.hist(df_sh['Porosity'].values, label='Shale', bins=30, alpha=0.6)
ax1.set(xlabel='Porosity (fraction)', ylabel='Density', title='Porosity Histogram')
ax1.legend()
```